# Add multiple values to one cell

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple table with an five columns.

One of these columns is a field with an array.
Lets say i have an entry with

```
id: 1
field 1: value on
field 2: value o
field 3: value b
field 4: value a, value b
```

Now i need a way how i can update the entry above and only insert additional values to the array so that it would look something like this:

```
id: 1
field 1: value on
field 2: value o
field 3: value b
field 4: value a, value b, new value
```

How can i do this using a MySQL table and PHP?

Comment: Do it with MySQL's `replace()`. That is all you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But what I am wondering now if this would be a good solution to my problem as i want to store timestamps in these cells whereas I wan to be able to query them afterwards. Would it be better to insert each timestamp into a new row?

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your problem clearly then you can do it very easily using php serialize() function.
here is an example how serialize() function works-

```
$data['value1'] = 'value_a';
$data['value2'] = 'value_b';
$insert['values'] = serialize($data);
```

and then just insert this array into your database column.